# Adding font to stimulsoft resources works in designer but is not affected in viewer

Tags: javascript, angular, stimulsoft

When I add a custom font to resources in dictionary of report at designer, it works in preview section.

But when saving the report and loading it in viewer, used fonts do not work (those elements that used added fonts are displayed by default font)!

Is there any configuration that must be applied after loading report in viewer?

Comment: Improved the language as far as I understood the question correctly...

Comment: i'm using StimulSoft report JS , this problem occurred at web browser